# Raw stack vs. generic Stack<Character>

Tags: java, char, stack, character, generic-collections

It's not an error, I just don't like having the warnings show up in Eclipse.

```
Stack is a raw type. References to generic type Stack<E> should be parameterized
```

I know I can fix it by providing the class Character as E, but since I'll be using `.charAt`, I would much rather simply use `<char>` because that's the type `charAt` returns. Is there a way for me to use char as the parameter, and if not, will I run into casting problems using `<Character>`?

Comment: What's wrong with `Stack<Character>`? You can't give `char` as type parameter.

Comment: So what is you're gonna fill in values in the `Stack` using `charAt()` method. You can specify the `Character` class as the type parameter for your Stack, and just add your `charAt` output to it. Autoboxing will happen internally and your `char` will be inserted in your `Stack` as `Character` without any fuss!

Comment: Ok thanks, I really wasn't sure if it would autobox or not, that was my biggest question, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you have to use `Character` and not `char` is that generic type parameters in Java cannot be primitive types.  There is no way around that.  If you want to use the standard Java collection framework, you just have to put up with this.

As far as the warnings are concerned:

- They are warnings, and can be suppressed.  You can do it in the source code (by using `@SuppressWarning` annotations), or by changing the Eclipse Java compiler preferences.
- It is always possible to write a genericised equivalent to any usage of raw types.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate Generic Types with Primitive Types. Refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#instantiate) for details.

You can use `Character` class. To get the primitive data type you can always use [charValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#charValue%28%29) method in `Character` class.